# Using AKMicrophone adds red bar after microphone node was removed

Tags: audiokit

In a part of my app i need to use AKMicrophone for analyzing user input. I use an AKBooster with 0 gain and everything works fine. If I go to background while the app records, iOS shows a red sign. As expected.

However if I then stop AudioKit and recreate the whole chain without the microphone node in the other part of the app it will still show red microphone when backgrounded. I tried using `AKMicrophone.detach()`, `AudioKit.detach()` to 0 effect. Just having this line:

```
var microphoneNode = AKMicrophone()
```

is enough to always have red microphone icon when the app is backgrounded.

Is this a known issue/expected behavior? Or am I missing some proper disconnect routine for microphone? Again. For my use case it is totally fine to use AudioKit.stop(), but it just doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Funny enough, the issue can be solved entirely by updating to latest AudioKit and using `AudioKit.shutdown()` instead of `AudioKit.stop()`.